# How do you set up Pushpool/Litecoin for windows?

Tags: litecoin, pushpool

I am hoping someone can point me to a decent tutorial as to how to set up a Litecoin Pushpool server for windows. Im not trying to build anything big just so that my friends and I can mine together. I already have MySQL Community installed and working properly, downloaded the pushpool php files as well as the Mining Farm extras.

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=10617.0

Though the only tutorials I have seen to implements those files are for Ubuntu? Don't know how well that reflects Windows so I have been stuck.

Would be willing to donate a small amount of bitcoin, not litecoin, to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done. There are windows equivalents for all of the programs you need to install.

1. Cron. Normally, I'd tell you to use the task scheduler, but it looks like the program you linked needs to run stuff every 5 - 8 minutes. [This tool](http://cronw.sourceforge.net/) seems to do  what you need. You'll need Perl too.
2. [PHP](http://windows.php.net/). Note that you need to use the command `C:\PHP5\php.exe -f`  instead of `php`.
3. MySQL.
4. [Apache2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html).

Answer (score 0):

Iam not aware of a pool software that supports windows (except p2pool which is way different than pooled mining).

From my own experience i can suggest eloipool (channel on freenode irc: #eligius)  as its as far as im aware the only maintained public pool software.

Please note, a pool and a frontend and a reward/payout system are different things. If you mine with your friends you will likely want to sharelog. Eloipool has postgres support.

(As im aware eloi took some code from pushpool)

May have a look on:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Poolservers

Also to note is security, if you run a pool with the bitcoind client on the same server your pool server is visible in IP log, you dont want to run a exploitable pool in this case.